# MX150 Not working with Thunderbolt 3 and HDMI on Ubuntu 18.04 (dual external monitors)

Tags: nvidia, external-monitor, displayport, thunderbolt

I am having an issue with an external monitor. The monitor is picked up and works fine over HDMI. I want to use my Thunderbolt 3 port and have connected a cable to the monitor's displayport.

I have the right drivers installed (I believe). But the monitor is not being picked up (fresh 18.04 install)

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001D10sv000017AAsd0000225Bbc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP108M [GeForce MX150]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

**UPDATE:** I restarted my primart external display and now it works over Thunderbolt. However a secondary external display over HDMI does not work and is not shown in device manager. If I unplg the thunderbolt connection the second display comes on and disappears when I plug the thunderbolt back in.

Any ideas ?

**UPDATE:**

I wonder if this is a hardware limitation, I have a Thinkpad T580